# filter Click event in document

Tags: jquery

I have the following code witch works fine:

```
$(document).on('click','.with-hidden-caption', function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: "+colum+")").matches || !$(this).parents(".my-wrapper").length) {
        $(this).toggleClass('show-caption')
        $(this).find('figcaption').slideToggle("fast");
    }
});
```

Now i would like to find out where in .with-hidden-caption' is clicked to toggleClass in depend where the click is. With other words: If the click is on newToolBar it shout not run.

Here my HTML:

```
    <figure class="with-hidden-caption">
<figcaption>Hello    
   <div class="newToolBar"> if here is clicked do something else but not $(this).toggleClass('show-caption') </div>
          </figcaption>
                            </figure>
```

How do I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.with-hidden-caption', function(){
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('newToolBar')) return;
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: "+colum+")").matches || !$(this).parents(".my-wrapper").length) {
        $(this).toggleClass('show-caption')
        $(this).find('figcaption').slideToggle("fast");
    }
});
```

We will check if the the element being currently clicked `e.target` has the class `newToolBar` then do nothing else execute the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class Name of the currently clicked element using

```
$(document).on('click','.with-hidden-caption', function(e){
   var clsName = e.target.className;
   if(clsName == 'newToolBar')
   {
     return false;
   }
   else
   {
     if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: "+colum+")").matches || !$(this).parents(".my-wrapper").length) {
        $(this).toggleClass('show-caption')
        $(this).find('figcaption').slideToggle("fast");
   }
}
});
```

is this what you need..?

Comment: thx Misam. It works, the problem is now that I have more than one class. I think the proposal from Palash is more felxible and works also.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on('click','.with-hidden-caption', function(){
    if($(e.target).closest('.newToolBar').length) return
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: "+colum+")").matches || !$(this).parents(".my-wrapper").length) {
        $(this).toggleClass('show-caption')
        $(this).find('figcaption').slideToggle("fast");
    }
});
```